# Javascript variable is set in one function, but undefined in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, scope

I have the following Javascript,

```
eventManager: {
    $musicGenres : null, // $musicGenres is the selector for a div-container of inputs
    musicGenres : [],

    // Functions
    handle : function(selectors) {
        selectors = (typeof selectors === 'undefined') ? {
            'musicGenres' : '#musicGenres'
        } : selectors; // selectors default values...
        this.$musicGenres = $(selectors['musicGenres']);
        console.log("CHANGED $musicGenres TO " + this.$musicGenres);

        this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(this.reloadMusicGenres);
    },
    reloadMusicGenres : function() {
        console.log("IN FUNCTION $musicGenres IS " + this.$musicGenres);
    },
```

, call the function `eventManager.handle()` on my page and trigger the change-Event of one of those inputs, which outputs

```
CHANGED $musicGenres TO [object Object]
IN FUNCTION $musicGenres IS undefined
```

what I don't understand. I've set $musicGenres to a new value, but in the reloadMusicGenres-function it stays undefined. Even when I manually access $musicGenres' value through the console by typing in `eventManager.$musicGenres` it outputs the right value.

Could anybody help me? That really worries me.

Comment: In event handlers, the context is the element, not the object containing the handler function.

Comment: the scope of your reloadMusicGenres is in the context of a change function... so `this` wont have that variable on it.. try `console.log("IN FUNCTION $musicGenres IS " + eventManager.$musicGenres);`

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how a `function` is invoked. You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fixate the value that should be used -- `.change(this.reloadMusicGenres.bind(this));`. Or, with [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

Comment: Thank you John Ruddell, I think this will be my solution, since I need to access the object on which the event handler is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` of `this` has changed. The easiest way to address the issue is to reference `this` outside the function, or pass a `data` object (as suggested by the two other fine posters, Richard Healy and AlliterativeAlice).

A third way is to explicity `bind` the context of `this`. Using jQuery, you can achieve this by calling `$.proxy`. So, this:

```
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(this.reloadMusicGenres);
```

becomes:

```
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change($.proxy(this.reloadMusicGenres, this));
```

`$.proxy` will return a new function, where `this` will always be bound to `eventManager`. If you're interested in moving away from jQuery, `Function.prototype.bind` is your answer (Edit: an example of which is provided by Zoltan's answer)

Here's some links for documentation on how to use these fine functions:

jQuery proxy: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Bind function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried in the handle method:

```
var self = this;
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(function () {      
     self.reloadMusicGenres();
});
```

Might be a scoping issue when the reloadMusicGenres function gets called.

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed out, your problem is context binding.

IMO the easiest way to fix your code would be to change this line

```
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(this.reloadMusicGenres);
```

to this:

```
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(this.reloadMusicGenres.bind(this));
```

This should solve your problem. No need to change anything else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the object to the change handler like this:

```
this.$musicGenres.find('input').change(this, this.reloadMusicGenres);
```

Then in `reloadMusicGenres()`:

```
reloadMusicGenres : function(e) {
    console.log("IN FUNCTION $musicGenres IS " + e.data.$musicGenres);
}
```